# Jwplayer not working on safari and IOs

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, jwplayer, mp4

I come today with issue using JWPlayer.

Everything is ok on Chrome, FF and Edge but not on mobiles devices and Safari's browser.. I get this error message :

Error loading media: File could not be played
According to documentation, I use wrong media format but it's works with all browser exept on mobiles devices and Safari's browser.

Here is my setup for JWplayer 7.8.2 client side:

```
<div id="preview_video>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("preview_video").setup({                                                                       
        playlist: [{
            sources: [{
                    file:"myfile.flv",
                    type: 'flv'
                },{
                    file:"myfile.mp4"
                    // fallback mp4 file in case flash is disabled or not allowed
                    type:'mp4'
                }],
            image:"myfile_image.jpg"
        }],
        primary : 'flash',
        aspectratio : "16:9",
        width: "100%"
    });
</script>
```

And here is my code from server side

```
if($_REQUEST["format"] == 'mp4'){
    $mediaPath = $myfile."mp4";
    $content_type = "video/mp4";
}else{
    $mediaPathPhoto = $myfile".flv";
    $content_type = "video/x-flv";
}
header("Content-Type: {$content_type}");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($mediaPath));
readfile($mediaPath);
exit();
```

After spend several hours through googling i come here hoping someone can help me..

Thx to you

Answer (score 0):

JWPlayer relies on the *Adobe Flash Player* browser plugin to decode & display FLV files. This plugin is not available on official Android or iOS browsers.

**solution**

Use MP4 format via HTML5 only. Both formats (FLV vs MP4) can contain exact same data (h.264 video with MP3 or AAC audio) but MP4 is supported in more devices & software.

iOS uses HTML5 and accepts MP4 only.

set `primary : 'html5'` and provide an MP4 link. The MP4 file can still be played by Flash (fallback) where there is no HTML5 support since *Flash Player* can decode either MP4 or FLV formats.